# Connected App Access to Sandbox Environments

Tags: connected-apps

If I have a connected app in a Sandbox environment, do those credentials go invalid after a day?

We've noticed that if we installed our Connected App in a Sandbox environment our App doesnt seem to connect to the sandbox environment after 24 hours.

Do we need to create a mechanism that refreshed the sandbox token to the connected app every 24 hours?

Answer (score 0):

The credentials are still valid, but your *access token* is not (and those two are different things).

An access token is effectively the same as a browser session, and your org's session timeout policy applies (if you've specified a timeout policy in your connected app, that takes precedence).

If you make a request using the access token after at least 50% of the timeout has elapsed, then the timeout will reset (and that can effectively keep a token alive indefinitely). Otherwise, if your access token times out, you'll need to go through the OAuth 2.0 flow that you're using again to obtain a new access token (or supply the refresh token if you're using a flow that generates a refresh token).